# I have a problem with this "Incorrect program output" --- Input --- help me

Tags: python, list, visual-studio, python-2.7, application-pool

```
import interface as In
from fecha import Fecha
class Empleado:
    def __init__(self,nombre,cedula,salario,dia,mes,anio):
        self.nombre=nombre
        self.cedula=cedula
        self.salario=salario
        self.mes=mes
        self.anio=anio
        self.dia=dia
        self.fecha =Fecha(dia,mes,anio)

    def __str__(self):
        return f' {self.nombre} con documento {self.cedula} salario {self.salario:.2f} fecha de ingreso {self.fecha}'

    def aumentar_salario (self,aumento):
        aumentos =self.salario*(aumento/100)
        self.salario +=aumentos

    def calcular_antiguedad(self):
        diferencia_mes=10-self.mes
        diferencia_anio=2021-self.anio
        diferencia_todo=(diferencia_anio*12)+diferencia_mes
        return diferencia_todo

    def gana_mas_que(self,f):
        if pablo.salario < alicia.salario:
            f=(alicia.salario > pablo.salario)
        return f


if  __name__ ==  '__main__':

    pablo =  Empleado("Pablo Ortega", 100, 5000, 1, 1, 2005)

    alicia=  Empleado("Alicia Ortiz", 200, 10000, 1, 1, 2006)

    In.imprimir(pablo)

    In.imprimir(alicia)

    In.imprimir(f"Antiguedad de Pablo en meses: {pablo.calcular_antiguedad()}")

    In.imprimir(f"Antiguedad de Alicia en meses: {alicia.calcular_antiguedad()}")

    pablo.aumentar_salario(20)

    alicia.aumentar_salario(10)

    In.imprimir("Despues del aumento de salario:")

    In.imprimir(pablo)

    In.imprimir(alicia)        

    In.imprimir(f"Alicia gana más que Pablo: {alicia.gana_mas_que(pablo)}")
```

Comment: What do you get, and what do you expect?

Comment: Your question is tagged [Python-2.7] but contains `f`-strings which didn’t exist before Python 3.6 and will raise a syntax error in earlier versions. Might that be your problem? If so, please bear in mind that as a beginner, you should not be investing time in learning Python 2. Those of us who still work in it do so because we have to support or migrate legacy code.